# Installing Ubuntu10.10 on Mac Book Air

Tags: macbook-pro, unix

I tried to install Ubuntu by following [this tutorial](http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-macbook-air-3-1-via-usb-flash-drive), however finding out that when I tried to boot Ubuntu it gave me the message operating system missing.

Does anyone has an idea what I should do now, or maybe help in providing another solution?

Answer (score 1):

What I did was I installed Windows 7 via BootCamp and then installed Ubuntu [via Wubi](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/).

This was a lot simpler than the tutorial that you linked to but it's also more expensive (i.e. you have to purchase a copy of Windows) and you didn't indicate whether that was even desirable.